# Cumulative of Cumulative measure power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: po]

Hi Team,
I need 2 output.
Output1 = Cumulative of No of Item.
Output2 = Cumulative of Output1.
Please help me.

Comment: What is Jan, Feb, March...? they are plain text? or month name you are picking from a Date value?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Date column from where you are picking the Month name, you can try this below 2 **custom column** code. I just considered first date of each month in the date column, but it will work for any date. this below column will give you cumulative vale per Year to Month-

**Note-** Based on your Date value, you may need some adjustment in the script. But using this logic, you should achieve your required output.

```
C1 = 

var current_row_date_month = your_table_name[Date].[MonthNo]

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[No Of Item]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[Date].[Year]),
        your_table_name[Date].[MonthNo] <= current_row_date_month
    )
)
```

```
C2 = 

var current_row_date_month = your_table_name[Date].[MonthNo]

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[C1]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[Date].[Year]),
        your_table_name[Date].[MonthNo] <= current_row_date_month
    )
)
```

Here is the sample output-

[image]